# Skype Web Control support

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper

I try to find a internet place where I could find support about the Skype Web Control (dedicated support web site, forum, chat, documentation). A place where I can report problem and find help.

Here are my issues, maybe someone has a solution:
I use the Skype Web Control with a Microsoft Chatbot (Azure, LUIS) and it works pretty well.

But the smileys are not displayed in the conversion when the user send one. Space are taken to display the smiley but no smiley in there. If the user is connected, the conversation in the Skype application displays well the smileys.

And when the bot answer with a smiley, it is displayed as text :) not replaced by an image. Is there a way to do it?

I also have the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content-type=application%2Fbond-compact-binary&client-id=NO_AUTH&sdk-version=ACT-Web-JS-2.9.0&x-apikey=xxx.
(Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions. To enable emojis you can customize webchat control. We did it and enabled emojies and other features too. Below is the link of source of webchat:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

For CORS issue (cross domain security issue) have you tried placing the code on ms azure app. We faced the issue, with our own server, but not on azure app. CORS can be configured using web.config too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took a look at the BotFramework-WebChat and I don't see anything about emoji. I tried the demo at https://botchattest.herokuapp.com/ and the smileys sent are displayed as text.
About CORS did you find a web.config configuration which fix the error? I tried `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` without success.

Comment: 1. You need to add emojis using any plugin. Make sure you take react supported plugin only. There are a lot of such plug in available.
2. For that error give a try hosting on azure app. This is CORS issue. Please search with CORS error, you will find some solutions. If no, then please reply, will find some good links for you.